# laravel path on server comes up 404

Tags: php, laravel

Everything is working fine using `php artisan serve` locally, but on the server every path besides `/` comes up not found.

I assume this has something to do with configuration, but not sure where to start. How can I get the routes working?

**Edit:** my routes

```
// works
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

// 404
Route::get('/map', 'HomeController@showMap');

// 404
Route::get('/assets/{filename}', 'HomeController@getAsset');
```

Comment: How can someone help without seeing any code, post `routes` please with other relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you didn't set up your web server to redirect all requests to Laravel.

http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

For Apache:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

For nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```